# Exporting from gitlab self-hosted projects with commit history to another gitlab self-hosted server

Tags: gitlab, migration

I am trying to export projects with all there commit history from gitlab server (self-hosted) version 11.6.3-ee and importing them to gitlab server (self-hosted) version 16.8.0.

I was able to export/import as file but it was without the commit history please any help?

a side question should I have to migrate the users and groups as well so that commit history would work?